# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN trying to access AWS lambda endpoint

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy a Node/Express app to AWS lambda using serverless. It seems to work, but **after several executions of serverless deploy, I get DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error when trying to access the endpoint**.

If I change to another AWS region, it works, but it happens again after a few executions of

```
serverless deploy
```

The output of serverless deploy command is always right, **no error shown**.

I guess this question lacks of information, but I don't know what I need to provide.

Comment: My guess is that this is a *client*'s problem instead of anything to do with API Gateway.

Comment: Yep, probably something related with serverless configuration, but I can't find the source of the problem